# Java EE @Singleton and @Startup: What's the point if it can get garbage collected due to inactivity

Tags: jakarta-ee, garbage-collection, singleton, ejb, startup

I have a @Singleton Java EE bean that has takes a significant amount of time to initialize its JAXB contexts.  To combat this, the @Startup annotation was added.  However, I noticed if the bean gets garbage collected periodically.  This is based on logging in its constructor.  Is there some config setting that can be utilized to essentially make the Singleton Java EE bean get init on container start (JBoss) and stay around until the JBoss is stopped?

@stdunbar I was just guessing it got recycled due to inactivity... the singleton is referenced by multiple @Stateless
@Oleg 
The application server is JBoss.  Prior to seeing this behavior my expectation was that a bean with the @Singleton annotation would get instantiated and live until the application server was shut down (this wasn't based on any reading etc.) but as i mentioned above I see the constructor getting called multiple times which makes me believe the @Singleton is getting recycled

Comment: What is the use case that the JVM has decided that there is nothing referencing it but you want to keep it around?  It'll be initialized again if needed again.

Comment: Can you name your applications server? Never seen such behaviour in Wildfly. I have Singleton which initializes for 1 minute, it does this only once.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could have mistaken about garbage-collecting you singleton and several instantiations of it. Because otherwise, it's a **direct violation of EJB specification**:

> A Singleton session bean is a session bean component that is
> **instantiated once per application**. In cases where the container is
> distributed over many virtual machines, each application will have one
> bean instance of the Singleton for each JVM.
>
> Once instantiated, a
> Singleton session bean instance **lives for the duration of the
> application in which it is created**. It maintains its state between
> client invocations but that state is not required to survive container
> shutdown or crash.

The quote above is taken from version [3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) but it's the same in this part for all the 3.x.

Instead of logging in constructor, I suppose you can try it in @PostConstruct method of your singleton, that would be more descriptive.

Comment: Ok I will double check.  Thanks